# iptables messing up Tomcat?

Tags: linux, http, iptables, ssl, tomcat

I encountered the following problem(s) using Tomcat 7 with iptables on.

1) Namely, there's this Tomcat 7 instance that I run on **server-1** (directly exposed), and this Tomcat instance hosts a REST web-service. Tomcat itself is configured with SSL (NIO, not APR/native), with `clientAuth="true"`. Keystores, certs, and everything seems to be set up OK and working.

On this server, iptables are up and running allowing all traffic from **server-2**, and the last rule in the filter INPUT chain is:

> -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Now, from **server-2**, I try to call the web-service and I fail with connection / read timeout exceptions.

2) Tomcat won't shut down - I get "No route to host" exception message when trying to shut it down via its shutdown script.

As soon as the last rule specified above in iptables on **server-1** is removed, both problems go away...  Both servers are running CentOS 6 64.

Can someone shed some light on this?

**EDIT**
Here are all the other current INPUT rules:

> // VPN Related
>   -A INPUT -s xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
>   // FreeRadius
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1812 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1813 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1812 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1813 -j ACCEPT
>   // Tomcat
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4445 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8345 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8007 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 4445 -j ACCEPT
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 8345 -j ACCEPT
>   // Allow all from server-2
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -s xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT
>   // System
>   -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
>   // Reject
>   -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Comment: We are going to need to see the other rules as clearly something is blocked that shouldn't be. At a guess, localhost is blocked on server-1 as that would prevent the shutdown script from working.

Comment: Thanks Mark... yeah, seems you guessed right for blocked localhost. I updated the question with other rules.

Comment: What about output rules? Is server-1 allowed to send data to server-2?